# Ending my tenure as a superuser moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

To the superuser community,

I have officially submitted my resignation as a superuser moderator to the community team. I would like to thank everyone who I have collaborated with over the years – my fellow dedicated moderators; all my fellow computer lovers who have contributed their knowledge, passion, and expertise; the many former members of the community team who taught me a great deal about building community with patience; and to every person who ever read a question or answer I wrote and found it useful.

It has been a long time since I have been active daily on superuser. Back in the day, I would spend many hours a week answering questions, working on the (now defunct) blog, processing flags, and chatting with the community. My career, while still involving computers, has taken me away from the hands-on, day-to-day technical details that apply to so many of the topics here. Shifting corporate priorities from Stack Exchange have finally pushed me to make this long-overdue decision to turn in the diamond badge and make way for new members to fill that role.

My experience on superuser was instrumental in my growth as a person, and I will always be grateful for my time spent here. I'll still drop in occasionally. Best wishes to all of you – may superuser live long and prosper!

Comment: Happy Trails to you!

Comment: Sorry for the tardy featuring. I cannot believe it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 33):

I totally get why you’re doing this. Thank you Nathan for your work and help here at SU. I’ll never forget how much time and effort we spent on different matters- the jokes, the camaraderie, the brainstorming on the blog posts and all the chat room madness. I wish you the best.

Answer (score 26):

We apparently found this home away from home one single day apart some 10 years ago. Those were heady days of answering, chatting and working to make the site a better place for users old and new. It was fun and, amongst a few other users, you were a crucial part of the Super User family.

It has been a long ride together, and I want to personally thank you for the years you spent moderating.

Answer (score 22):

Too many goodbyes this month.

❤

This was one of the folks I have to thank for me being who I am now - and I'd say as one of the mods before me, I learnt a lot from Nathan. And a few Hijinks.

Good Luck out there.

Answer (score 7):

Sad to see you go, but know you can always hang out with us in Root Access anytime :)

Live long, and prosper, my friend

Answer (score 6):

Nathan Hinkle, though, I have only read three of your posts, including this one, you sure seem like a very intelligent being, and through this post you have made it clear you are a very intelligent person indeed, and very thoughtful.

  Farewell nhinkle, peace and happiness to you.

Answer (score 3):

Nathan was instrumental in the earlier days of SU, especially as we continued to find our footing in enforcing quality, tag cleanups, and trying to help the community mature overall. He was always laid back and willing to answer questions and mentor others. I found nhinkle a pleasure to work with and one of the best!

All the best to you nhinkle. It's been a pleasure! Reach out anytime. Happy Trails!